# WordPress custom fields with multiple values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if it's possible to have Custom Fields with 2 values in WordPress posts...

Here are two examples:

[image]

[image]

For example if I want to have
    a field named "`projects`"
    with two values

```
value 1 "name"
value 2 "url"
```

Is it possible to do that?

BTW, I know I can do `projects_name` & `projects_url` in separate fields but that's something that doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: Are you using update_post_meta?

Comment: nope, I don't use it..

Comment: You can store them as a comma-separated list and "explode" them later...

Comment: How are you saving your custom fields?

Answer (score 1):

First off you are using post_meta as that is were custom fields is stored secondly why not just have 2 custom fields one for name and one for link you can retrieve them the same way or as previously suggested make the value delimiter separated so Text*Link them simply explode

```
$linkVar =  explode('*', get_post_meta($post_id, 'your key');

echo '<a href="' . $linkVar[1] . '">' . $linkVar[0] . '</a>';
```

Comment: because there're going to be 7/8 of those links/names... and people that are going to use it are not really into blogs and stuff I'd like to make it as simple as possible for them...

Comment: That is simple as once you have added once everything else should be done via backend

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer will be helpful for some more people who use **"Custom field suite (Field Group)" WP plugin**:

```
$loop = CFS()->get( 'your_param_slug' );
foreach ( $loop as $row => $label ) {
   echo $row; // or: echo $label
}
```

(See more: https://usewordpress.com/plugin-guides/custom-field-suite/custom-field-suite-displaying-loop-values/ )